# What will happen if I update a DLL being used by a running program over a COM interface?

Tags: c#, com

I have an un-managed piece of code accessing my managed DLL over a COM interface. What will happen if I update my DLL without switching off the other program?

Thanks

Comment: The fact that COM was the intermediary by which the DLL was loaded into the process changes nothing. Once loaded, as far as Windows is concerned, a loaded DLL is a loaded DLL - COM or not. It behaves the same as any other DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably nothing.

It's most likely the DLL file will be in use, and you will not be able to replace it. You will get an error saying the file is in use by another process.